# Parse JSON response got from AJAX request through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm geting a JSON response with an AJAX request through JavaScript.

Here is the response:

```
{"responseCode":400,"errors":false,"submitted":false,"content":"some content","notice":""}
```

My Goal is to get the content:

```
"some content"
```

The json variable is the data in my case. So, I have tried with:

```
data.content
```

But I am geting an empty string.

Any idea on how to access the string?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you parsed the json response? If not try JSON.parse(data)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Did you first parse json ?

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

than read `data.content`

Comment: Yup, or use something like jQuery.parseJSON for older browsers.

Comment: @Dejo Dude its Work Like a charm :)