# MongoDb: Got My AJAX Response, but how to Convert it?

Tags: ajax, mongodb

I need the server's response in the right format to allow me to traverse it like a list of MongoDb documents.

The console.log shows the data I want as [{"_id": "0YHYT54", etc.}], so it's all there.

However, it is string, making my attempt to traverse it as a MongoDb document fail.

```
function clientChanged(selectInput) {

    if (selectInput.selectedIndex === -1)
        selectInput.selectedIndex = 0;

    selectedClientId   = selectInput.options[selectInput.selectedIndex].value;

    getClientMatters(selectedClientId, (matters) => {

        console.log("returned Type: " + typeof matters);

        <-- I need to process the returned data here, but it is string.
    });

}

function getClientMatters(clientId, cb) {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            cb(this.response);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "../matters/getByClientId?clientId=" + clientId, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Here is my model, which returns the data from the server:

```
Matters.getOpenMattersByClientId(clientId, function (err, matters) {
    if (err) {
        return res(err);
    } else {
        return res.json(matters);
    }
});
```

Also, this is my first attempt at using AJAX to get my MongoDB data.  If the above code reveals other issues, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Converting the response to json may work.
[Converting to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478127/parse-json-response-got-from-ajax-request-through-javascript)

Comment: It did.  Thanks!